# Update table just once for each match?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have table `Player`, what are each 10 minutes populated by `cron` from `xml` results feed.

Results feed is feed for football fixtures results, and i want from some player nodes get data about players from each team and insert/update it into table Player.

I have logic problems.

This are columns in `Player` table:

```
`PlayerID`,
`PlayerName`,
`PlayerNo`,
`PlayerTeam`,
`Season`,
`TeamID`,
`TeamName`,
`LeagueID`,
`League`,
`Apps`,
`SubbedIn`,
`SubbedOut`,
`Minutes`,
`Goals`,
`GoalsP`,
`Assists`,
`Yellow`,
`Red`
```

Now i want to add +1 each time when i see some player in `lineups` tag and update table or +x when player score Goal when his id is in `goal` tag, problem is that i want just Players in table Player and if i use it like this:

```
UPDATE PLayer SET Goals = Goals+$x
```

It will add new goal each time when cron execute script, i need somehow to identify is goal from fixture updated, if yes, don't update it again.

So for example:

```
<match id='321'>
<home name='Chelsea'>
<goal player='Matic'/>
<goal player='Hazard'/>
</home>
</match>

<match id='323'>
<home name='Chelsea'>
<goal player='Ivanovic'/>
</home>
</match>
```

Now when each time cron executes this feed it will update table again and add new goals for Matic, Hazard, Ivanovic, i want to add goal just once for each match if player scored one goal. So for just one day Matic for example will have hundreds goals for Chelsea...

Purpose is that i want to get all goals for each player in season, but i want to get goal for example just first time when cron see that player in `goal` tag, not again.

I hope that you understand me. Thanks..

Comment: I guess that somehow you need to keep track of which xml "message" has been processed so that you don't end up processing them more than once. Perhaps this match id would help?

Comment: How i can track all id's, easiest way is to add matchid as PK, but than i will get thousands rows in table player, what needs to have data for each player in single row...

Comment: save proccessed id in memory or in file. You need save only the last value because, i think, it is incremented

Comment: Hmm smart guys :) Maybe that is solution, read from file match id's what are was processed. if(isin_array($matchid,$file)==FALSE)update();

Comment: I can't save just last value, because it reads whole xml feed what takes whole season and many id's... So if i remember just last than it will update all old id's what are already updated...